# Applying a font to text in an input field with HTML characters and tags

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am applying a custom non-English non unicode font to some text.

On some occasions this may contain English text. In such a case this English text is enclosed within a font tag as follows:

```
<small><font face="Arial,Helvetica">Some sample text</font></small>
```

I apply the font using the following:

```
@font-face {
     font-family: "my_custom_font";
     src: url(static/fonts/my_custom_font.woff);
}

.my_font {
    font-family:"my_custom_font";
    font-size:180%;
}
```

When I apply this font to a div it is displayed as expected

```
<div class="my_font">

<?php print_r($data["title"]); ?>

</div>
```

However when I do the same to an input field I do not get the same result

```
<input name="title" class="my_font" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($data["title"]);  type="text">
```

Instead of rendering the text in English as expected the font is being applied to the HTML tags resulting in junk characters. If I don't use htmlspecialcharacters then the input field terminates at the occurence of " after 'face'

Is it possible to treat the input field like the div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a contenteditable div to render the text and a hidden form element to store its value solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't use the font tag.

> Do not use this element! Though once normalized in HTML 3.2, it was
>   deprecated in HTML 4.01, at the same time as all elements related to
>   styling only, then obsoleted in HTML5.
>
> Starting with HTML 4, HTML does not convey styling information anymore
>   (outside the  element or the style attribute of each element).
>   For any new web development, styling should be written using CSS only.

Then in your input field you are missing the closing of the php code. It should be

```
<input name="title" class="my_font" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($data["title"]); ?>" type="text">
```

And add a meta tag for the character set used on the page

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

And yes, you can style your input field anyway you like it.

```
.my_font {
    font-family:"my_custom_font";
    font-size:180%;
}
```

Comment: Only the point about closing the PHP command is relevant to the question.